# Running GWT in SuperDevMode

Tags: java, maven, gwt

Running $`mvn gwt:run-codeserver` throws this error:

```
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1255 msecs]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-datanucleus-plugin:1.1.4:enhance (default) @ web ---
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from/to local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk): No connector available to access repository local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk) of type legacy using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] No files to run DataNucleus tool 'org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer'
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1:run-codeserver (default-cli) @ web <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1:run-codeserver (default-cli) @ web ---
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
[ERROR]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:488)
[ERROR]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[ERROR]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
[ERROR]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
[ERROR]     ... 6 more
[ERROR] Exception in thread "main" 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.901s 
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 20 15:33:27 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 46M/356M
```

What could be the problem with this? The GWT version my app uses is `2.5.1` and also with the GWT Maven plugin.

I'm not sure if my app is missing something.